# How to init ORB from property file?

Tags: java, initialization, corba, orb

I would like to init my ORB from property file (normally I init it like this, while running my examples:  `./app -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService`)

I wrote a simple code:

```
private static String[] readConfigFile()
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String arg[] = new String[1];
    try 
    {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {}
    arg[0] = prop.getProperty("ORBInitRef");
    return arg;
}
```

and then tried to init my orb:

```
clientsORB = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(readConfigFile(), null);
```

but there are some errors:

```
2012-11-01 12:15:36 com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 127.0.1.1; port: 900"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2172)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2193)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:223)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:236)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:119)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:168)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:136)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.invoke(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:99)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.resolve(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1174)
        at ClientConnection.connect(ClientConnection.java:68)
        at Client.main(Client.java:303)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:525)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:164)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:78)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:206)
        ... 12 more
```

My config.properties file:

`ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService`

What I did wrong? **When I init my ORB normally, everything is great, so its not the code issue, its definitely problem with initialization from file.**

Comment: Ever tested what is returned by your `readConfigFile()` compared to `args[]`. (JUnit testcase available?)

Comment: What ORB are you using? Have you checked the documentation? Some ORBs will already read options from a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `-ORBInitRef` to the ORB arguments also. Compare it to the commandline you normaly use. ALL the arguments have to be passed to the `ORB.init()`

config.properties:

```
ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService
```

Java Code using it (ReadProps.java)

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.omg.CORBA.ORB;

public class ReadProps {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ORB clientsORB = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(readConfigFile(), null);
    }

    static String[] readConfigFile() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String[] orbarg = new String[2];

        try {
            // load a properties file
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
            // get the property value and print it out  
            orbarg[0] = "-ORBInitRef"; // <---- NEEDED
            orbarg[1] = prop.getProperty("ORBInitRef");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return orbarg;
    }

}
```

Comment: this code: http://pastie.org/private/d1ccwxdsh8sx1nawevsouw prints: http://pastie.org/private/rvyz6aiwjmudqqblmola when I run it that way: `java App  -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService` and my config file : `ORBInitRef -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService` (as you suggested) but still have same errors

Comment: it won't as `args` is never assigned.

Comment: but I passed it in orb initialization: `clientsORB = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(readConfigFile(), null);` is that wrong too?

Comment: "-ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService" are two! arguments

Comment: ooo, right I see now. Sorry, I was a bit confused but now its all clear, thanks :)

Comment: huh, errors again: http://pastie.org/private/ws4wxecxgtm74bwrmshidg. where line 318 is a line: `ORB clientsORB = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(readConfigFile(), null);`

Comment: Could be, NameService is not running? Test with telneting to `localhost port 2809`

Comment: strange, really o_O My NameService is running

Comment: Please post `ClientConnection.connect from ClientConnection.java:64`

Comment: What NameService do you use? "OBJECT_NOT_EXIST" means it isn't there. By the way. Code and error messages are easier to read if line numbers correspond.

Comment: just to show the problem I wrote a simple program with the same error http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/14655906/file.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18932/discussion-between-tuergeist-and-yak)